# Main method not working properly while creating a database with JDBC in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am a beginner to coding. Currently, I am learning to create databases with JDBC in java. I loaded the latest sqlite JDBC onto IntelliJ (sqlite, because that's what my instructor is using).

But now my main method has encountered some problems.It is not importing the necessary files, not highlighting my mistakes and not even giving suggestions for efficient coding.
When running the code, it throws `ClassNotFoundException` and Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.Main.

Can anyone please mend my main method?

This is the Run> Edit Configuration window:
[image: This is the Run> Edit Configuration window.]

This is the code I am trying to execute with the run window and the project pane:
[image: This is the code I am trying to execute with the run window and the project pane.]

Comment: Instead of posting a picture of your code please make the effort of posting the code itself. Cheers.

Comment: please share exactly what exception you are getting here

Comment: I posted the picture so that the code, the runtime error and the project pane is clearly visible because I have a hunch that there is something wrong with Main class file path.

Comment: You have syntax errors: missing close parenthesis when calling `getConnection()` and closing double-quotes on the path to the database file.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Thanks for pointing that out. If IntelliJ was highlighting my mistakes, you would not have to.

Comment: Please do not post pictures, post the actual code or output as a code formatted block of text in your answer.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have already explained my reasons, please check the previous comments.

Comment: @ManishJoshi if you'd configured IntelliJ properly it'd have highlighted your mistakes.

Comment: @jwenting I did configure IntelliJ properly. I am guessing that the new update meddled with my previous settings somehow. Also, this would be a way better place if instead of pointing out silly syntax errors, people would try to understand the root problem from the question and simply post the solution. Nay to nitpickers.

Comment: @ManishJoshi nope, if you've not set a folder as source folder that's your error, not the IDE's.

Comment: @jwenting Well then how come there was no problem in executing my code before updating the IDE. I am new to all this coding and IDE, why would I manually try to change the source folder without having a clue about what I was doing? However, even though I am new to coding, even I know that after an update, it is not entirely impossible for a software to change the previous settings due to some new bug. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source folder is not seen as a source folder by IntelliJ, therefor the java file is not interpreted as source code. This means it does not do any analysis on the files to report errors, nor is the file compiled.

Right click on the `src` folder and mark it as a source folder (right click on `src`, *Mark Directory as*, *Sources Root*). This could  be an indication that the way you created your IntelliJ project is not correct for a Java project.

Comment: Thanks for not pointing out my silly syntax errors and trying to understand the root problem instead. Cheers!